# Passing variables between php pages

Tags: php, kohana

I'm new to the Kohana Framework. I have a problem - How can I pass the variable `$title` from Layout.php to Head.php?

In controller:

```php
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Admin_Quanly extends Controller_Template {
    public $template='admin/layout';
    function _showWithTemplate($subview,$title)
    {
        $admin_path = 'admin/';
        $this->template->head = View::Factory(''.$admin_path.'head');
        $this->template->subview = View::Factory(''.$admin_path.''.$subview.'');
        $this->template->title = $title;
    }
    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->_showWithTemplate('subview/home','Trang quản trị hệ thống');
    }
}
```

In view Layout.php:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <?php echo $head?>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

In view Head.php:

```xml
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?=$title?></title>
<base href="<?=URL::base()?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/ddaccordion.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$admin_path = 'admin/';
$this->template->head = View::Factory(''.$admin_path.'head');
$this->template->head->title = $title;

$this->template->subview = View::Factory(''.$admin_path.''.$subview.'');
$this->template->title = $title;
```

Note the `$this->template->head->title = $title;` you need to pass it along manually to the head view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set() or bind(). See example:

```
$view = View::factory('user/roadtrip')
    ->set('places', array('Rome', 'Paris', 'London', 'New York', 'Tokyo'));
    ->bind('user', $this->user);
```

Ref: http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/mvc/views

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is set_global

http://docs.kohanaphp.com/core/view#set_global

It will allow you to set a variable for all your views to be able to use. You won't be passing it per say but it will still do what you want.

Example fix

```
function _showWithTemplate($subview,$title)
{
    $admin_path = 'admin/';
    $this->template->head = View::Factory(''.$admin_path.'head');
    $this->template->subview = View::Factory(''.$admin_path.''.$subview.'');
    $this->template->set_global('title', $title);
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. Globals are alway to be avoided. Even more so if it's called `title`

Comment: I know this has been a while but this is not setting a Global variable. This sets a local variable that Kohana will then pass to all views it encounters in the current view. This is done recursively. Again, it is NOT a global variable, Kohana just calls it that.

Comment: This should be threated like one. All your views will be overridden with that value. You should always avoid them because they create unexpected behavior. Setting the variable independently for both views is a better solution than making it a global over all views.